# Orcad search using Tcl

Tags: orcad

I mostly use Orcad Lite to browse schematics, doing a lot of component/net search.

How can I search using Tcl console?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure it is supported in the Lite version, but in Orcad CIS there is a Find and Replace Text function in the Tcl Utilities menu. I have used it mostly for global search and replace using regular expressions. For component/net search you are better off using the Edit > Browse > Parts / Nets. Also there is a search box on the main toolbar. I find it easier to search a PDF of the schematic than inside Orcad.